# sas ods.rtf output headline w/in macro

Tags: macros, sas, output, title, ods

i´m having trouble getting a headline for a macro since for some reason the title produced by the gplot routine overwrites the predefined headline (title1) what am i missing?

```
data one;
input state $2. sales @@;
datalines;
VA  5200 
SC  9800 
NC  7500 
GA  12500 
NY  17600
;
run;

goptions reset=all ftext='calibri' htext=2 gunit=pct;
symbol1 i=none f='calibri' v='$' h=4 c=green;
axis1 order=(0 to 20000 by 5000) offset=(0,0) label=none;
axis2 minor=none offset=(3,3) label=none;

* place white space above the title using the LS option;
title1 h=4 'Sales by State --- SAS/Graph-Controlled Order on X-axis' ls=1;

* place white space on left and right of the graph;
title2 a=90 ls=1;
title3 a=-90 ls=1;

footnote1 'BASED ON:  http://support.sas.com/kb/24/916.html' ls=1;
footnote2 ls=1;

%macro gplot2(data);
proc gplot data=&data;
plot sales*state / vaxis=axis1 autovref haxis=axis2;
format sales dollar8.;
run;
quit;
%mend;
OPTIONS nonumber nodate orientation="landscape";
ODS RTF FILE='C:\temp\SAS_output_test.rtf' startpage=no  
    keepn;
ODS RTF NOTOC_DATA;
ODS escapechar='^';
ODS noproctitle;
ODS RTF TEXT='^S={just=left} Dataexport XX-XX-XXXX';
title1 '^S={just=right font=("Arial", 10pt, bold)} test'
   '^S={just=right font=("Arial", 10pt, bold)} Page ^{pageof}';
%gplot2(one);
quit; 
ods rtf close;
```

the page layout should look like this:

```
OPTIONS nonumber nodate orientation="landscape";
ODS RTF FILE='C:\temp\SAS_output_test.rtf' startpage=no  
    keepn;
ODS RTF NOTOC_DATA;
ODS escapechar='^';
ODS noproctitle;
title1 '^S={just=right font=("Arial", 10pt, bold)} test'
   '^S={just=right font=("Arial", 10pt, bold)} Page ^{pageof}';
ODS RTF TEXT='^S={just=left} Dataexport XX-XX-XXXX';
ODS RTF startpage=now; 
ods rtf close;
```

thanks a lot, fleischfressende

Comment: A title/footnote doesn't get printed until it encounters a PROC, so when the GPLOT is encountered the title there overwrites the previous title. You can try ODS TEXT instead.

Comment: yeah, i´m aware of the fact that there are conflicting titles and that they get overwritten. so my question was for a workaround. or how to define it to get the headline without the conflicts. or could that be defined in a proc template without being overwritten? i´m sorry for those questions, i´m new to sas...

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Use ODS RTF text instead. 2. Slide titles all down one number - start at title 2 instead? I can't test your code because I don't have SAD Graph. If you don't get an answer here post on communities.sas.com under graphics forum for one of the SAS graph guys to help.

Comment: ok, thanks, will try the text option. any idea how to get that in the headline of the word-document?
about your second suggestion: i´ve tried to kind of downgrade all titles down to title4 -> doesn´t make a difference. at least not in the macro we´ve written (it´s somewhat different than the one i´ve posted).

Comment: or could suppressing the title1 that gets generated by gplot be an option?